# Printing picture x times in django template

Tags: django, templates

Say I have an integer value that I output to a django template say x. I also have a picture that I want to print x times in a row.  How would I output this picture x times in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick but ugly hack to get this done would be using the [make_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#make-list) filter:

```
{% for i in "xxxx"|make_list %}
    {{ image_html }}
{% endfor %}
```

This would print the image four times (as there are four characters in the string).

A cleaner way would be to pass a list into your template using `range()`:

```
context['image_print_range'] = range(1, 5)
...
{% for i in image_print_range %}
    {{ image_html }}
{% endfor %}
```

Another solution (probably the cleanest one) is a custom template tag or filter, e.g.:

```
@register.simple_tag
def print_multiple(value, count):
    """Print a value multiple times."""
    return ' '.join([value] * count)
```

And in your template:

```
{% print_multiple "foobar" 4 %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you add it into a list in the view x times to iterate over it in a `{% for %}` tag, or you create a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) to repeat the image url x times.